# How do I change button visibility from other class?

Tags: java, android, button, visibility

So basically I have a button in my MainActivity

```
 Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

What is the way to change my button visibility from my GameView class?

```
if(state == State.PAUSED){
//change button visibility
}
```

Comment: what is GameView? a fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recommended way to achieve this is to have a local `BroadcastReceiver` (Sub-class of `MainActivity`) which will read message from a broadcast, and according to that set the visibility of the button.

And

Send broadcast form the `GameView` with the proper message.

Seems pretty complicated but trust me, its the best and recommended way to do it.

[Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) for the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make public static field Button button1;

And if you want to call button in another class just call that class and button like example

FirstClass.button1

Comment: static fields aren't the recommended way to do it

Comment: why it isn't recommended?

Comment: Android coding standards say so. Once the Activity is killed by the OS, or the View is no longer needed and can be garbage collected, it'll be null, so you get a NullPointerException when using this approach. It's better to define a method on the activity to act on its button and pass around the activity itself instead of exposing view variables to external classes

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep a reference to the view ( The button ) you want to change , and change it in any way you see fit

```
button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

or
button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your **Button button1** as static global variable in MainActivity like

```
public Static Button  button1;
```

then your GameView code will be

```
if(state == State.PAUSED){
  MainActivity.button1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Comment: Static variables aren't the recommended way to do it, though

Comment: I know that @cricket_007. LocalBroadcast Receiver is the best solution. but I gave him an instant solution.

Comment: When I am trying to find it by id i get this error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity.

Comment: I think your visibility changing code in a non static method. If it is make that method static also.

Comment: It works fine, but how do I set an onClickListener without findViewById for my button now?(In xml file a have a button with id button1)